# Conditionally show apex:pageBlockButtons

Tags: apex, visualforce

I would like to conditionally show the buttons below based on what is in a label.

```
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock mode="mainDetail">
     <!--Conditionally show these buttons if  a profile is in the label.-->
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Approve" action="{!approve}" disabled="{!approveFlag}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Reject" action="{!reject}" disabled="{!rejectFlag}" />            
            <apex:commandButton value="I am Reviewing" action="{!iamreviewing}" disabled="{!reviewFlag}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Escalate to Legal" action="{!escalatetolegal}" disabled="{!escalateFlag}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
     <!--   .... -->
  </apex:form>
```

I am not sure how to do this as there is no traditional if statement

Comment: Use rendered attribute for the page block button tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visualforce we have rendered attribute which we can use as replacement of If statement. You can use that here.

Its syntax is similar to ternary if condition. Here is one example for you

```
 <apex:inputField id="xxxif2" value="{!Object.Fieldtobedisplayed1}" rendered="{!IF(Object.picklistfieldapiname1 ='picklist value 1' ,true,false)}"/>
```

If the field value match with the value in single quote then display the component else hide. So your code will be

```
<apex:pageBlockButtons rendered="{!renderedConditionHere}">
            <apex:commandButton value="Approve" action="{!approve}" disabled="{!approveFlag}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Reject" action="{!reject}" disabled="{!rejectFlag}" />            
            <apex:commandButton value="I am Reviewing" action="{!iamreviewing}" disabled="{!reviewFlag}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Escalate to Legal" action="{!escalatetolegal}" disabled="{!escalateFlag}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

Answer (score 2):

use rendered attribute in [`apex:pageBlockSection`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlockSection.htm) to make it conditionally rendered.

```
<apex:pageBlockButtons rendered="your condition">
```

It exists for almost all the Visualforce components.